# Trouble creating a shell in C (Seg-Fault and ferror)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets, ferror

I have been following a tutorial on how to make my own shell but I have been stuck for a couple days now.

Two things:

1. When this code is compiled and ran, it will randomly have segmentation faults and I cannot figure out why.
2. The if statement `if (ferror != 0)` always seems to be true. which is odd because I do not understand why **fgets()** is failing in the **main()** function.

Any information on these topics (or other topics about creating this shell) would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAXSIZE 512

int parseCmd(char *cmd, char *args[])
{
    printf("LOGGER: parseCmd(cmd=%s, args=%p)\n", cmd, args);

    char cmdDelims[] = {' ','>'};

    char *cmdReader;
    cmdReader = strtok(cmd, cmdDelims);

    int i = 0;
    while (cmdReader != NULL)
    {       
        args[i] = strdup(cmdReader);

        printf("LOGGER: args[%d]=%s\n", i, args[i]);

        cmdReader = strtok(NULL, cmdDelims);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printToLine(char *args[])
{
    int length;
    length = sizeof(args) / sizeof(char);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < length)
    {
        printf("%s\n", args[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{   
    char *in;
    in = malloc(MAXSIZE);

    char *args[15];
    char *cmd = NULL;

    int errorBit = 0;
    int terminationBit = 1;
    char error_message[30] = "An error has occurred\n";

    char inDelims[] = "\n";

    while (terminationBit)
    {
        printf("mysh>");

        // get input from command line
        fgets(in, MAXSIZE, stdin);
        if (ferror != 0)
        {
            perror(error_message);
        }

        // get pointer to command line input w/o the newline
        cmd = strtok(in, inDelims);

        // parse the command into separate arguments
        errorBit = parseCmd(cmd, args);
        if (errorBit)
        {
            perror(error_message);
            exit(1);
        }

        printToLine(args);

        // check if the user wants to exit the shell
        if (strcmp(*args, "exit") == 0)
        {
            terminationBit = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Here are some outputs:**

```
**[ray@12] (6)$ mysh**
mysh>1 2 3
An error has occurred
: Success
LOGGER: parseCmd(cmd=1 2 3, args=0x7fff4a50b080)
LOGGER: args[0]=1
LOGGER: args[1]=2
LOGGER: args[2]=3
1
2
3
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
**[ray@12] (7)$ mysh**
mysh>1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
An error has occurred
: Success
LOGGER: parseCmd(cmd=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, args=0x7fffba053d70)
LOGGER: args[0]=1
LOGGER: args[1]=2
LOGGER: args[2]=3
LOGGER: args[3]=4
LOGGER: args[4]=5
LOGGER: args[5]=6
LOGGER: args[6]=7
LOGGER: args[7]=8
LOGGER: args[8]=9
LOGGER: args[9]=10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
mysh>1 2 3
An error has occurred
: Success
LOGGER: parseCmd(cmd=1 2 3, args=0x7fffba053d70)
LOGGER: args[0]=1
LOGGER: args[1]=2
LOGGER: args[2]=3
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: Why don't you check the return value from `fgets`? You can't detect EOF by checking `ferror(stdin)`.

Comment: After looking more closely I am assuming I need to free my args variable before I reuse it. I do not understand why I get seg-faults for the parsing of an array with only 3 elements though.

Comment: See my update answer for that one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `ferror` error, you need to test `ferror(stdin)`, not `ferror`. The latter is the function address, which will never be zero:

```
if (ferror(stdin) != 0)
{
    perror(error_message);
}
```

For at least some of the segfaults, this does not do what you think:

```
length = sizeof(args) / sizeof(char);
```

This will tell you *how many bytes are used to store the pointer*, which is 4 or 8 depending, and *not* the number of arguments.

So if you have four (or eight) arguments, it will *appear* to work. If you have more, it will seem to ignore some arguments. And if you have less, it will fetch the missing arguments from across the Void, resulting in a (almost sure) segmentation fault.

You need to calculate `length` independently and pass it along, or store some terminator in `args`, for example adding a NULL argument after the last valid argument you find:

```
        cmdReader = strtok(NULL, cmdDelims);
        i++;
    }
    args[i] = NULL;
    return 0;
}

void printToLine(char *args[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (args[i])
    {
        printf("%s\n", args[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```